# Set column value when multiple rows exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a flattened data set that includes **Order#**, **Shipment#**, and **ShippingCharges**. There can be multiple shipments per order, but shipping charges are collected at the order level. Here is an example dataset:

```
1, 1, $5.00
2, 1, $6.00
2, 2, $6.00
3, 1, $10.00
3, 2, $10.00
3, 3, $10.00
4, 1, $4.00
```

As you can see, the order's **ShippingCharges** are repeated for each shipment in the data set. I need to come up with a query that will set **ShippingCharges** to 0 when there are multiple shipments on the order. The resulting dataset would look like this:

```
1, 1, $5.00
2, 1, $6.00
2, 2, $0.00
3, 1, $10.00
3, 2, $0.00
3, 3, $0.00
4, 1, $4.00
```

It is important to note that the **Shipment#** numbers do not all reset to 1 for each order. I did this in the sample dataset to make it easier to follow. **Shipment#** is actually a sequential integer that increments each time a shipment is created, so a simple `UPDATE dataset SET ShippingCharges=0 WHERE Shipment# > 1` is **NOT** the answer.

It seems like I would need to do an `UPDATE` when there is more than 1 shipment for an order, but only for rows where the Shipment# is greater than the minimum Shipment# for the order.

Any ideas what that query might look like, especially for Microsoft Access?

Comment: What if you set `1` and `2` to zero (in your `$10.00` example) and kept the value for the number that matched the count of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE dataset SET ShippingCharges=0 WHERE Shipment# > 1 is **NOT**
>   the answer.

Then set the charge to zero when *Shipment#* does not match the minimum *Shipment#* for that *Order#*.

```
UPDATE dataset
SET ShippingCharges=0
WHERE [Shipment#] <> DMin("[Shipment#]", "dataset", "[Order#]=" & [Order#])
```

If the *Order#* field is text datatype, add quotes in the third `DMin` argument (*Criteria*):

```
DMin("[Shipment#]", "dataset", "[Order#]='" & [Order#] & "'")
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was not aware of the DMin function and was trying to accomplish it with pure SQL within Access and was failing miserably. This worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome.  When you have some free time, check out the other Access domain functions: `DLookup`; `DMax`; `DCount`; etc.  One of the reasons they can be useful is that they can help overcome Access' query is not updatable complaint.  But they are not portable to other SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

This was written in Oracle, so not sure if you can do similiar in Access.
Sub select to the table to see if it's the min shipment or not then you use the shipment charge or 0 it out.

```
select a.order_num, a.shipment_num, 
case when a.shipment_num = (
  select min(b.shipment_num) 
  from order_table b
  where b.order_num = a.order_num
) then max(a.shipment_charges) else '0' end
from order_table a
group by order_num, shipment_num
order by order_num, shipment_num
```